# Reading content from excel using jmeter

Tags: excel, jmeter, watson-conversation

I am trying to use jmeter for chatbot testing. How to read data from an excel sheet using jmeter and pass that excel data to a chatbot(Watson Conversation bot) and validate the bot response against the response given in the excel sheet and provide the load metrics like time taken to generate response, no of users etc.
Regards,
VHC

Comment: Can you read it as CSV with CSV Data Set Config?

Answer (score 3):

Given you have [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/) jar in [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) you should be able to use [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) for getting data from Excel files.

1. Download [tika-app.jar](https://tika.apache.org/download.html) and save it under "lib" folder of your JMeter installation
2. Restart JMeter to pick the .jar up
3. Use the code like:

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables;
   import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
   import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
   import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
   import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
   import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


   InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("/path/to/your/file.xlsx"));
   Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(in);
   in.close();
   Sheet sheet1 = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
   Row row = sheet1.getRow(0);
   Cell a1 = row.getCell(0);

   vars.put("A1", a1.getStringCellValue());
   ```
4. Assuming everything goes well you should have the contents of first cell in first row in first sheet available as `${A1}` JMeter Variable.

More information: [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-every-performance-tester-should-know-about-extracting-data-files-jmeter)